# Can not find post file in github by using jekyll

Tags: html, github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

This is my github pages . I have already create gh-pages brench.

I want to create markdown file and use jekyll to convert it to .html file.

It can be successfully shown on my localhost.
(auto-generate _site and .html pages)

But I upload the whole directory to github .

The index file can be loaded , but post file cannot.
(click the post link,it show 404 error page.)

What happened to this ?

This is my jekyll github link:
https://github.com/larrywhy/jekylldemo/blob/gh-pages/index.html

This is my pages:
http://larrywhy.github.io/jekylldemo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At **_config.yml** file, change the baseurl from "/jekyll_demo" to "/jekylldemo".

You misspelled.